# Allow an active directory group to ssh into server

Tags: active-directory, sshd

I'm trying to get my AD group `SSH_Users` to be able to SSH into our server. I added a line to the config file in `/etc/sshd`: `AllowGroups ssh_Users` and tried `ssh_Users@domain.com`. This does not work. I get an access denied message when trying to log in. I also created a local group called `localsshgroup` on the server and added the group `DOMAIN.COM\ssh_Users` to the local group. Still the same error.

I was able to get the domain admins to be able to log in by using `domain\admins`, but I can't get the group called `SSH_Users` that I want to to be able to log in, and I created a test user and added them, but the user still cannot log into the server.

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the group name in lower case letters, e. g. `ssh_users@domain.com`.